# on prod server Laravel Sanctum is not working

Tags: laravel-9, laravel-sanctum

laravel Sanctum not working on server.
it is working on local and test server also but when i migrate the project to prod server then this is not working

tried

php artisan config:cache
composer dump autoload

but did not worked.

want to make sanctum work properly

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you have to show the error you got